# Joining dataframes from lists of unequal length

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two lists of dataframes that I want to combine, I have tried the following:

```
A <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
                var1 = c(3,4,5),
                var2 = c(6,3,2))
B <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
                var1 = c(4,4,5),
                var2 = c(6,7,3))
C <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
                var1 = c(1,4,8),
                var2 = c(9,2,3))

list1 <- list(A = A, B = B, C = C)
list2 <- list(A = A, B = B)

combined <- map2(list1, list2, full_join, by = 'ID')
```

This returns an error that the two lists are of different lengths. The only other way I have thought of is to add a blank dataframe to the second list so they are the same length.

Is it possible combine the two lists so that I get a single list where A1 has been joined with A2, B1 with B2, and C1 remains as it is?

Edit: Its been highlighted that I havent named the elements of the list, I have named them now

Comment: What if `list2` had been `list(A, C)`?

Comment: It still returns the same error `Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 3
* `.y` has length 2`

Comment: @tom91 I think the questions was aiming the direction of "what is the expected output if `list2` had been `list(A, C)`"? Do you just want to join A with A, B with B etc or something else?

Comment: If the lists are not named then how would you know how to join 1-by-1? i.e. A with A and so on? If your list2 is `list(A, C)` then you are merging A with A and B with C...

Comment: Ah I see, that makes much more sense! I would want it to return A1 joined with A2, B1 remain the same, C1 joined with C2. If its easier returning B1 as if it had been joined with a blank dataframe would also work

Comment: @Sotos does that mean the only way is to add in a blank dataframe named C to list2 in my example?

Comment: No, your lists have to be named (i.e. `list(A = A, B = B)` etc...) in order for you to match A with A and so on. You can not do anything If they are like that...

Comment: You can either name your list elements and match the names (in which case you don't need to provide C in list2) OR keep working with positions but then you need to put placeholders in your lists.

Comment: @Sotos Ohhhhhh! sorry, yes I'm being very slow here. I should have put that in the original example. In my actual data the elements are named. My mistake!

Comment: Then you have your answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have named lists, then we could:

```
list1 <- list(A = A, B = B, C = C)
list2 <- list(A = A, B = B)

x12 <- intersect(names(list1), names(list2))
x1 <- setdiff(names(list1), names(list2))
x2 <- setdiff(names(list2), names(list1))

combined <- c(
  map2(list1[ x12 ], list2[ x12 ], full_join, by = 'ID'),
  list1[ x1 ],
  list2[ x2 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep working with positions, you can also pass placeholders and handle them in the combining logic. Something like that:

```
skip <- tibble(ID = integer(0))

list1 <- list(A, B, C)
list2 <- list(A, B, skip)
list3 <- list(A, skip, C)

combined  <- map2(list1, list2, full_join, by = 'ID')
combined2 <- map2(list1, list3, full_join, by = 'ID')
```

Note how `list2` and `list3` would look exactly the same if not for the placeholders!

More generically:

```
list1 <- list(A, B, C)
list2 <- list(A, B, NULL)
list3 <- list(A, NULL, C)

combine <- function(list1, list2) {
   purrr::map2(list1, list2, function(df1, df2) {
      if (is.null(df1)) return(df2)
      if (is.null(df2)) return(df1)
      full_join(df1, df2, by = 'ID')
   })
}

combined  <- combine(list1, list2)
combined2 <- combine(list1, list3)
```