# How to merge dataframe lists of unequal length?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind

This question is similar to [Joining dataframes from lists of unequal length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934147/joining-dataframes-from-lists-of-unequal-length).

I have a `shiny` script where I am using `fileImport` to allow the user to import a variable number of data files. Each datafile is then split into a list of dataframes, and these are imported as a list. So I have a list of a list of dataframes.

The input datafiles have two format possibilities, one may be 129 dataframes long, the other may be 67 - where the 67 is actually a subset of the 129 (so all 67 are present in the 129, but not all 129 are present in the 67). I am then trying to `rbind` the dataframes by name.

A reproducible example:

```
# Some data
df.l1 <- list(df1 = data.frame(A = letters[1:10],
                               B = rnorm(10, 5, 1)),
              df2 = data.frame(A = letters[11:20],
                               B = rnorm(10, 10, 2)))

df.l2 <- list(df1 = data.frame(A = letters[1:10],
                               B = rnorm(10, 5, 1)),
              df2 = data.frame(A = letters[11:20],
                               B = rnorm(10, 10, 2)))

df.l3 <- list(df1 = data.frame(A = letters[1:10],
                               B = rnorm(10, 5, 1)),
              df2 = data.frame(A = letters[11:20],
                               B = rnorm(10, 10, 2)),
              df3 = data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:10],
                               B = rnorm(10, 15, 2)))
```

This works when binding lists of equal length (e.g. df.l1 and df.l2)

```
df.two <- list(df.l1, df.l2)
list.merged <- do.call(function(...) Map(rbind, ...), df.two)
```

But fails when binding list of dataframes with variables lengths.

```
df.three <- list(df.l1, df.l2, df.l3)
list.merged <- do.call(function(...) Map(rbind, ...), df.three)
```

Giving the error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter
2: In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter
```

As I said above, similar questions have been asked, but this situation is unique given the variable number of lists I am trying to merge. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a robust handling of this I would use `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist`. First you bind each list, then you bind at the upper level:

`tidyverse` version:

```r
library(dplyr) 

bind_rows(lapply(df.three, bind_rows))
```

`data.table` version:

```r
library(data.table)

rbindlist(lapply(df.three, rbindlist))
```

Not only will this handle weird corner cases you don't expect, but it will also be much faster than `do.call`.

## edit in response to comment

Try this:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df_names <- unique(unlist(sapply(df.three, names)))
result <- list()
for (n in df_names) {
  result[[n]] <- map(df.three, n)
}
map(result, dplyr::bind_rows)
```

Comment: This is really simple. Thanks so much! But for the record, what I want is a final list of merged dataframes, so you only need to do `lapply(df.three, bind_rows)` - don't need the `bind_rows` wrapper.

Comment: Accepted the answer before I saw that this doesn't quite do as I want it to do... This function is binding df1 & df2 within df.l1 and df.l2, and df1, 2, and 3 within df.l3. What I want is to have a final df.all list containing the results in df1 from l1 plus df1 from l2, and l3.